# Using get in the given sentence

Tags: verbs

You don't want to know how I **get** when the month's nearing it's end, and I'm broke.

You don't want to know how I **am** when the month's nearing it's end, and I'm broke.

Or

You don't want to know what I'm like when the month's nearing it's end, and I'm broke.

Are all the above sentences grammatically correct? I looked up the several ways get can be used, and came across one that suggest it can be used instead of **be** in certain situations, and I've actually heard people use get as it has been used in the first sentence, so I can't seem to be certain that it's okay to use it that way. Is it?

Answer (score 1):

"Become" means to change state. ""I have become X" means that the "I am now X although I previously was not X."

So "become" has a broader field of meaning than "be" but includes "be." So I would rather say that usage more equates one sense of "get" with "become" rather than "be." In other words I equate

"You don't know how I get when I am broke" and

"You don't know what I become when I am broke."

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I got your idea absolutely right, but here are a couple of suggestions:

If you mean that by the end of the month you may spend or lose all of your money, the expression is ["go broke"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/go%20broke).

Also, if you mean that your interlocutor doesn't what to know what happens to you when you go broke or what you may become, the expressions may be "[what becomes/willl become of](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/ru/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9/become-of-sb-sth) me when I go broke" or "what I will become when I go broke".

So, the idea you're trying to convey may be expressed

> You don't want to know what becomes/will become of me/what I (will)
>   become at the end of the month when I go broke.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to know how **I get** when the month's nearing it's end, and I'm broke.

You don't want to know how I am when the month's nearing it's end, and I'm broke.

**Both are correct.**

**get** in the first means to "how I become".

You can **get mad (angry), get angry, get happy, get silly, get tired.**

**Get can be used with a number of adjectives describing someone's state of mind.**

He gets [becomes] so angry when you tell him to spend less money.

He got so happy when he passed the exam.

To create a question with this use of get, often, **how** is used.

**How does he get** when you give him bad news?
**He gets annoyed.**